# Need to popup modal when you click on a cell in a grid

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I need a modal from bootstrap to popup when I click on a cell in my grid. I have the modal defined but I don't know how to link this to when I click on a cell in my grid.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1>Title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        This is body. 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <input class="btn btn-default" value="Close">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
  </div>
```

`

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach((e)=>{
e.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
```

Above is my definition of the modal, and below is the script that has an event listener when you click on a cell in a grid. How would I link the two?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on bootstrap docs: [Bootstrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#methods)

You need to select the modal element by its id, then use the method show(). It will be something like this:

```
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), {
keyboard: false
})
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach((e)=>{
e.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
myModal.show()
}
```

Edit:

If you are using bootstrap 4, it will be something like this:

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach((e)=>{
e.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
$('#myModal').modal('show')
}
```

[More info on docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#usage)

Answer (score 0):

`$('.modal').modal("show")`

Bootstrap defines a `modal` function which accepts a parameter. Use `"show"` to show, `"hide"` to hide and `"toggle"` to toggle visibility.

[Bootstrap Modal Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

```js
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('td');
cells.forEach((e) => {
  e.addEventListener("click", () => {
    $('.modal').modal("show");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.2/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-2rNj2KJ+D8s1ceNasTIex6z4HWyOnEYLVC3FigGOmyQCZc2eBXKgOxQmo3oKLHyfcj53uz4QMsRCWNbLd32Q1g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">

      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h1>Title</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            This is body.
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

            <input class="btn btn-default" value="Close">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```